# Golang: using Windows 10 API / UWP / System.WindowsRuntime?

Tags: winapi, go, windows-runtime, uwp, winrt-xaml

Using `syscall` in Go how can I call the UWP APIs within Windows 10? I have seen and tried many *win32* examples, but when I tried using `System.WindowsRuntime.dll` it was a no-go; specifically, I received:

```
panic: Failed to load System.WindowsRuntime.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

*(this was at runtime, the binary built fine)*

I tried building both with a standard `go build` as well as

```
go build -ldflags="-H windows"
```

example code:

```
var(
    windowsRuntime      = syscall.NewLazyDLL("System.WindowsRuntime.dll")
    getDiskFreeSpace    = windowsRuntime.NewProc("GetDiskFreeSpace")
)
```

*Note: Other variants tried:*

```
windowsRuntime      = syscall.NewLazyDLL("System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll")
```

&

```
windowsRuntime      = syscall.NewLazyDLL("WindowsRuntime.dll")
```

Anyone been able to get this running or have any advice on the matter?
As always, *greatly* appreciated!!

Comment: GetDiskFreeSpace lives in kernel32.dll (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935(v=vs.85).aspx ). So you should have windowsRuntime = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")

Comment: Yes, where did you get `System.WindowsRuntime.dll` from? Are you trying to call the `GetDiskFreeSpace()` method of a specific UWP class? If so, you're in for a world of hurt...

Comment: Right you are - `kernel32.dll` it is, not sure where I got that from, I am trying to retrace my steps, in any event, the `System.WindowsRuntime.dll` was not found with `panic: Failed to load System.WindowsRuntime.dll: The specified module could not be found.` whereas when I had the wrong function/procedure name `GetDiskFreeSpace` I received `panic: Failed to find GetDiskFreeSpace procedure in Kernel32.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.` So `System.WindowsRuntime.dll` is definitely missing. Now just to figure out where if that is even the proper name. I'll get back to you briefly.

Comment: By the way, you must use the Unicode function name, that is why the procedure wasn't found -- so `GetDiskFreeSpaceW` and you'll be good - just in case others come across this question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file like this:

```
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zfree.go free.go
//sys getDiskFreeSpace(pathName string, sectorsPerCluster *int, bytesPerSector *int, freeClusters *int, numberOfClusters *int) (err error) = GetDiskFreeSpaceA
package main

func main() {
   var bytesPerSector, freeClusters, numberOfClusters, sectorsPerCluster int
   getDiskFreeSpace(
      `C:\`,
      &sectorsPerCluster,
      &bytesPerSector,
      &freeClusters,
      &numberOfClusters,
   )
   println("bytesPerSector", bytesPerSector)
   println("freeClusters", freeClusters)
   println("numberOfClusters", numberOfClusters)
   println("sectorsPerCluster", sectorsPerCluster)
}
```

Then build:

```
go generate
go mod init free
go mod tidy
go build
```

Result:

```
bytesPerSector 512
freeClusters 12511186
numberOfClusters 25434879
sectorsPerCluster 8
```

https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/mkwinsyscall

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you found "System.WindowsRuntime.dll" because as far as I can tell, it doesn't exist (unless you manually made a DLL named that).

As for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll: it's part of .NET Framework, not Windows, and it is a managed DLL. You cannot load such DLLs using syscall.NewLazyDLL. What's more, that DLL doesn't really contain any Windows APIs - just glue for .NET to be able to work with them.

You're probably looking for functions like [RoGetActivationFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br224648(v=vs.85).aspx) in combase.dll.